# Stationarity at different confidence levels

Tags: time-series, unit-root, stationarity

My question is, when looking for cointegration between two variables, I need to make sure that they are not stationary in levels.  However, one of the variables is not stationary at the 5% level but it is stationary at the 10% level.  How do I interpret this?  Do I regarded as a stationary, a weakly stationary or a non-stationary variable?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "stationary in levels" means?

Comment: Stationarity in levels is opposed to stationarity in first differences, i.e. testing the initial data for unit root (before differencing)

Comment: A general approach to significance is "pick and stick". Pick the significance level, and stick to it. E.g. pick 5%, and use it to decide in your inference issues, don't change it because you didn't like the outcome.

Comment: So your subsequent uses of "level" are not related to that initial use? Are you then talking about conducting a test and getting a p-value between 5% and 10%?

Comment: @whuber, yes sorry about that. The inital "levels" is different from the 5 and 10% significance level. The second sentence is what I am talking about.

Comment: @Aksakal, actually I do like the results, because one of my pairs turned out cointegrated and the other one not, so I can contrast them. I am, however, wondering whether the fact that one particular variable bearly passed the test at the 5% level and did not at the 10% level, could be an explanation for the lack of cointegration between this particular pair. What do you think?

Comment: Pick and stick. Pick 5%, and forget 10%, or otherwise. There's no reason to be jumping between.

Comment: @Aksakal You are correct, as a general principle. But I wonder whether there might not be a subtlety here: the OP appears to want to make a *single* decision from the results of *two* related tests. As such, *neither* p-value is the appropriate one for the decision.  What may be needed is a way of combining the two results into a single p-value.

Comment: Aksakal, alright, thank you! I will look for a different reason why cointegration might not occur.

@whuber, the idea is that in order for cointegration to exist, both variables have to be non-stationnary initially, but stationary after taking first differences (this is just the first step of the approach). So I am not combining the results, I am testing them seperately. Anyway, thank you for you help :)

Comment: On the contrary, you have just made it perfectly clear you *are* combining the results. In order to make your decision you have to determine that (1) the first differences of the first series are stationary and (2) the first differences of the second series are stationary.  *That* is the combination to which I refer.  *Neither* of the separate p-values for those two tests are  the correct p-value for the *one* decision you propose to make. This is a simple example of a multiple comparisons problem.

Comment: which cointegration test you're running? Why not use Johansen test?

Comment: I use both the Engle and Granger approach and Johansen's test. I am doing it for a term paper, so I can't  just take the results and leave it, I need to analyze them :) They both give me the same results though. What was bothering me was that one of the variables is so close to stationarity, so I wondered whether it would introduce a bias